# SAXON - XPath, Resolving Variable with Node and Primitive value

Tags: java, xml, xpath, saxon, jaxp

I have a case of evaluation like :

```
$asset eq 100 and $asset/name() eq 'p0:current_asset'
```

which should return `true()`, variable `$asset` need to be resolved as primitive and node value in same evaluation, I'm using `XPathVariableResolver` interface to resolve variable when evaluation is running.

Returning `TinyElementImpl` when resolving variable with

```
public Object resolveVariable(QName variableName)
```

Doesn't solve the problem, I'm using JAXP implementation of SAXON-HE.

Is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

We (Saxonica) haven't documented very clearly exactly what kinds of `Object` our implementation accepts as the result of the JAXP `resolveVariable()` method, and I'm in the process of fixing that. Returning any `NodeInfo` (including, therefore, an instance of `TinyElementImpl`) should work fine.

If you're using Saxon-HE, then it's not schema-aware, so the typed value of an element will always be `untypedAtomic`, therefore comparison with an integer isn't going to work. The simplest fix, though some readers might find it confusing, is to change the condition to `+$asset eq 100` - the unary plus operator forces a type conversion.

I wouldn't write `$asset/name() eq 'p0:current_asset'` either, because it's dependent on the namespace prefix. Better is to write `$asset[self::p0:current-asset]`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.

"Change the expression". I want, but I Can't. the expression comes from external party.

Actually the expression is not literally "$asset/name() eq 'p0:current_asset'", actually the expression is long xpath expression that has variable $assset , which is treat as primitive value in one section of expression and node value ($asset/name()) in another.

Comment: If the expression is wrong and you can't change it, then I don't know how to help you.